# What are Heroku traffic costs?

Tags: heroku

I can't find any information on what are the traffic costs on Heroku.

For example what does a traffic of 1 gb cost me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't find an official reference but I am almost sure they are free.
This is one of the thing I like with Heroku. In my opinion they overcharge the rest of their services but the free bandwidth is very nice.

They do however have a soft cap their [policy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#network):

> Network bandwidth must not exceed 2TB per month.

Comment: The quoted text is no longer available on the page behind the link.

Comment: It is: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#network states "Network bandwidth is soft limited at 2TB per app per month."

Comment: What would "soft cap" mean here?